# Prevent heroku to redirect from http to https on subdomain

Tags: heroku, https, dns

I have an app created on Heroku and I added subdomain to it:

```
some.page.example.com
www.some.page.example.com
```

Then, according to [this](https://help.heroku.com/VKRNVVF5/what-is-the-correct-dns-cname-target-for-my-custom-domains), I've pointed these names to proper Heroku names with my DNS provider like this:

```
some.page.example.com CNAME some.page.example.com.herokudns.com
www.some.page.example.com CNAME www.some.page.example.com.herokudns.com
```

I'd like to serve this page under http, apparently Heroku internally redirects traffic to https - it returns 301 when trying to access page via http. Of course finally it fails (e.g. ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR in Chrome or SSL_ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR_ALERT in Firefox), after redirecting, beacuse there is no certificate set up on this Heroku app.

**How can I prevent Heroku from doing this?**

P.S. What's funny, I have other site on Heroku, with root domain pointing to this, and it works like a charm. :/

Comment: multi-level subdomain won't work for https, as the certificate is i guess only for 1 level subdomain. eg. somepage.example.com and not some.page.example.com

Comment: @mdeora, I'd like use just http - I have no certificate.

Comment: Check in the config set,  config.force_ssl = false

Comment: if you still face issue share the domain name you are using.

Comment: @mdeora, thanks for help! It turned out that in nginx.conf file (I'm using PHP environment) - there was forcing redirect to http. :) Now it wokrs like a charm.